# Xpath selecting data after the <br/> tag

Tags: python, xml, xpath, scrapy

I have this html:

```
<div class="sys_key-facts">
  <p>
   <strong>Full-time </strong>1 year<br>
   <strong>Part-time</strong> 2 years
  </p>
</div>
```

I want to get the value of Part-time(After Part-time), which is:

```
2 years</p>
```

My Xpath code is :

```
//div[@class="sys_key-facts"]/p[strong[contains(text(), "Part-time")]][preceding-sibling::br]/text()
```

but this is returning empty. Please let me know where I am mistaking.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `p[preceding-sibling::br]` means that paragraph has line break sibling while `br` is actually a child of `p` - not a sibling

So you can update your XPath as

```
//div[@class="sys_key-facts"]/p[strong[contains(text(), "Part-time")] and br]/text()[last()]
```

or try below XPath to get required output:

```
//div[@class="sys_key-facts"]//strong[.="Part-time"]/following-sibling::text()
```

Comment: Thanks very much for super quick reply, your given code is working, Thanks again